# Putting Drupal node's comment form in a modal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Does anyone know of a module that will allow me to have more of a "facebook"-y feel to node comments?  I.e. a modal window with the comment form, and AJAX  update?

I can program it myself, I guess, but one of the fun parts of Drupal are the plug and play modules. :)

Thanks!

EDIT:

Or can anyone point me in the direction of someone who has done something similar?  My searches haven't yielded much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments

Comment: Sweet, I don't think this has a modal option though.  Still, it helps a lot.  Thanks. :)